# How to retrieve edge device Master Driver Configuration Store file

Tags: volttron

From linux command prompt how do I retrieve the [Master Driver Configuration Store](https://userguide-ilc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) file to upload for the ILC agent config? Am running VOLTTRON 8.1.3

If I do a `$ vctl status` I have these agents running.

```
UUID AGENT                           IDENTITY                          TAG        STATUS          HEALTH
02 actuatoragent-1.0               platform.actuator                 actuator   running [3071467] GOOD
3c bacnet_proxyagent-0.5           platform.bacnet_proxy             proxy      running [3060006] GOOD
eb forwarderagent-5.1              forwarderagent-5.1_1                         running [2947263] GOOD
14 listeneragent-3.3               listeneragent-3.3_1                          running [2998418] GOOD
35 platform_driveragent-4.0        platform.driver                   master     running [3144087] GOOD
7d testthreeagentagent-0.1         platform.testthreeagent           test_three running [3098409] GOOD
c6 volttron_openadr_ven-1.0.1.dev5 volttron_openadr_ven-1.0.1.dev5_1            0
```

Am I supposed to export this in JSON as a file? `$ vctl config list platform.driver`

This will list all BACnet device config files in CSV format. Any help appreciated...

***EDIT***

If I do:

`$ vctl config get platform.driver config`

This only prints:

```
{
  "driver_scrape_interval": 0.05,
  "publish_breadth_first_all": false,
  "publish_depth_first": false,
  "publish_breadth_first": false
}
```

Which I don't think is what I need for the ILC algorithm config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use the ILC configuration generator you need the platform.driver config store.

It is a file in your VOLTTRON_HOME, by default here:

```
~/.volttron/configuration_store/platform.driver.store
```

Answer (score 0):

vctl config get platform.driver drivername

where drivername is devices/foo/bar/baf or config.csv or whatever...
if expecting json output then add --json flag

Comment: Craig I added an edit to the post to show more info...